# Cannot acquire connection to Excel

Tags: excel, ssis, foreach-loop-container

I have a package with a `ForEach` Loop Container that is looping through Excel files in directory.  Everything is fine until I add `@User::Excel` to the expressions box in the ExcelFile Path connection manager properties.  Then I always get this error:

```
...DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER......failed with error code 0xC02020096...
```

I have been dealing with this all day yesterday and this error is killing my deadline.  I have everything setup just like any other package I have run with ForLoop and Excel.  Why is this time giving me so many problems?

May someone please guide me through some troubleshooting?  I have tried everything I know.

Comment: Rather than downvote my question and bail out...why don't you give me suggestions on how to improve the question...I don't even think this question is worth a downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparantly the package didn't like my `ForEach Loop` container in a `Sequence Container`...took the loop out of the `Sequence Container`, reconfigured, put back in the Sequence Container and worked fine.